# res.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am making an api call and recieving the data, however, I am having trouble sending the data back to my js file. I tried using res.send but I am getting an error. I can't seem to figure out how to send the information back to the javascript file. (I took my key out of the request link. For security reasons, however, I am getting the data back from the api call). The only problem I am having is returning the data to the frontend javascript file.

This is the Javascript file that sends the original request:

```
/ ********** options button function makes api call to get selected cities forecast *****************

function getCityForecast(e){


     var id = document.getElementById('cities');
     var getValue = id.options[id.selectedIndex].value;
     var suffix = getValue + ".json";

     var newObj = JSON.stringify({link : suffix});

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/", true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     xhr.send(newObj);

     xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if(xhr.readyState === 4){
             console.log(xhr.response);
             console.log('recieved');
         } else {
             console.log('error');
         }
     }
}
```

My server.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');


// ****************** Middle Ware *******************
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));



var retrievedString;
// **************** Post Request *******************
app.post('/', function(req, res){

var link = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/forecast";
retrievedString = link.concat(req.body.link);

request = http.get(retrievedString , function(res){
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(data){
         body += data;      
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(parsed.forecast.txt_forecast);
        res.send(parsed.forecast.txt_forecast);
    });
})

    .on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening')});
```

Answer (score 8):

You are overloading the definition of the variable `res` which is also what you called the response variable for your Express route handler method. In the callback function of the request, use a different name for that variable - for example:

```
request = http.get(retrievedString , function(resDoc){
```

Comment: Thanks @SylonZero Yep that was the issue. I changed it to: request = http.get(retrievedString , function(response){ , and all of the corresponding variables and it worked.